# Highchart linegraph update issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

The issue is shown below.

`c2chart1` and `c2chart1p` are identical graph and shares same data. Issue is `c2chart1` is getting updated, but not `c2chart1p` for the second time.

```js
$('#update').bind('click', function() {
  c2updateLineGraph(2, [
    [0, 105993],
    [25, 659727],
    [50, 648727],
    [75, 636627],
    [100, 636627]
  ]);
  c2updateLineGraph(3, [
    [0, 115993],
    [25, 659727],
    [50, 648727],
    [75, 336627],
    [100, 236627]
  ]);
  setTimeout(function(){ 
  c2updateLineGraph(2, [
    [0, 5993],
    [25, 659727],
    [50, 648727],
    [75, 636627],
    [100, 63667]
  ]);
  c2updateLineGraph(3, [
    [0, 125993],
    [25, 259727],
    [50, 648727],
    [75, 536627],
    [100, 236627]
  ]);
  }, 8000);
    
});

var c2graphdata = [{
  name: 'Current year',
  data: []
}, {
  name: 'Reapair v1',
  data: []
}, {
  name: 'Repair v2',
  data: []
}, {
  name: 'Replacement v1',
  data: []
}, {
  name: 'Replacement v2',
  data: []
}, {
  name: 'Facelift v1',
  data: []
}, {
  name: 'Facelift v2',
  data: []
}, {
  name: 'Reconstruction v1',
  data: []
}, {
  name: 'Reconstruction v2',
  data: []
}];

function c2updateLineGraph(index, data) {
  c2chart1.series[index].setData(data, true);
  c2chart1p.series[index].setData(data, true);
}

var c2chart1 = Highcharts.chart('container1', {
  series: c2graphdata
});

var c2chart1p = Highcharts.chart('container2', {
  series: c2graphdata
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container1"></div>
<div id="container2"></div>
<button id="update">Update charts</button>
```

Comment: Please, add your code to question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is using `data` variable twice in `setData()` method. Highcharts use this variable as a reference (library doesn't copy this array). Solution is simple, use `data.slice()`:

```
function c2updateLineGraph(index, data) {
  c2chart1.series[index].setData(data.slice(), true);
  c2chart1p.series[index].setData(data.slice(), true);
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hhh2zx3w/1/

Answer (score 1):

Well, I made fiddle based on your code.

See this. :)

[HighChart updated](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/3coyjtc8/1/)

I don't know how it works but, both init functions have to separate.

```
function chart1Update(index, data) {
    c2chart1.series[index].setData(data, true);
}
function chart1pUpdate(index, data){
    c2chart1p.series[index].setData(data, true);
}
```